# Is there a term for this (two words sound like one word)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

Tell her 
and teller

Or cellar
and sell her

Comment: Rathony, good catch, I find the other post quite helpful in answering this one.  I marked it as answered and as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Try [homophone](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homophone), defined by **Merriam Webster** as

> A word (one of two or more) that is pronounced like another word but is different in meaning, origin, or spelling.

Full definition is

> One of two or more words pronounced alike but different in meaning or derivation or spelling (as the words to, too, and two)
>
> A character or group of characters pronounced the same as another character or group

Comment: Oh, I thought homophones had to be only a single words, so it can be two as well right?

Comment: @jian Yes, as defined by the dictionary and accepted colloquially.

Comment: @jian Homophones are used for same pronunciation but different spelling or meaning.